# Retrieve a parent node using AEM query builder

Tags: aem, query-builder

I need to retrieve a parent node using AEM Query builder.

For instance, this is my query:

```
path:/content/test/us/bar
1_property:product
1_property.operation:exists

2_property:product
2_property.value:8003170008212
```

This query allow me to retrieve the following elements:

```
1) /content/test/us/bar/table/jcr:content/releated/product/2  
2) /content/test/us/bar/chair/jcr:content/releated/product/1
```

Using this query, one can retrieve all elements placed under /content/test/us/bar which contain 8003170008212 as value of product property.

Starting from the previous bullet points I need to return just the parent, so for example:

```
1) /content/test/us/bar/table
2) /content/test/us/bar/chair
```

I can achieve my target programmatically, iterating the results and using 3 times the getParent() method.

I'am wondering: is there a way to get it with query builder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the property that you are searching for is always present at a known path, the query can be rewritten as

```
path=/content/test/us/bar
1_property=jcr:content/related/product
1_property.operation=exists

2_property=jcr:content/related/product
2_property.value=8003170008212
```

This would then result in

```
/content/test/us/bar/table
/content/test/us/bar/chair
```

which avoids looping through the result and finding the parent nodes.

For e.g., the following query in my local environment

```
path=/content/we-retail/language-masters/en
1_property=displayMode
1_property.operation=exists

2_property=displayMode
2_property.value=singleText
```

results in

```
/content/we-retail/language-masters/en/experience/wester-australia-by-camper-van/jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/contentfragment
/content/we-retail/language-masters/en/experience/arctic-surfing-in-lofoten/jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/contentfragment
/content/we-retail/language-masters/en/experience/steelhead-and-spines-in-alaska/jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/contentfragment
/content/we-retail/language-masters/en/experience/hours-of-wilderness/jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/contentfragment
/content/we-retail/language-masters/en/experience/skitouring/jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/contentfragment
/content/we-retail/language-masters/en/experience/fly-fishing-the-amazon/jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/contentfragment
```

But rewriting the following query to

```
path=/content/we-retail/language-masters/en
1_property=jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/contentfragment/displayMode
1_property.operation=exists

2_property=jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/contentfragment/displayMode
2_property.value=singleText
```

results in

```
/content/we-retail/language-masters/en/experience/wester-australia-by-camper-van
/content/we-retail/language-masters/en/experience/arctic-surfing-in-lofoten
/content/we-retail/language-masters/en/experience/steelhead-and-spines-in-alaska
/content/we-retail/language-masters/en/experience/hours-of-wilderness
/content/we-retail/language-masters/en/experience/skitouring
/content/we-retail/language-masters/en/experience/fly-fishing-the-amazon
```

Comment: I have just tried it but it does not work. The query you suggested to me returns 0 results. Which is your AEM version? Mine is 6.2. Thanks

Comment: Okay, starting from yours answear I got my solution.